# Can you use a shared Redis cache across different cloud/compute platforms?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, cross-platform, hybrid-cloud

We are looking to move our GPU based services to a cheaper specialized compute platform. Our backend is hosted on GCP and we're using a Redis Memory store between several services in GCP. Happy to switch to another Redis provider if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it [appears](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#differences_between_managed_and_open_source_redis) GCP Memory Store for Redis is a large subset of the open source Redis. Being the two protocol-compatible, you may easily point your service to any non-GCP Redis setup.